# Is $f(x) = x\sin x$ is uniformly continuous on $ [0,\infty)$?

Tags: real-analysis

> Is $f(x) = x\sin x$ is  uniformly continuous on $ [0,\infty)$?

**My attempts:**

I know that composition  of uniform continuous function is uniform as $g(x) = x$ and $f(x) = \sin x$

Now $g(f(x)) = f(g(x)) $  so it  is uniformly continuous...

Comment: In fact, $g\bigl(f(x)\bigr)=f\bigl(g(x)\bigr)=\sin x$.

Comment: You want $g(x)\cdot f(x)$, not $g(f(x))$. Also, your using the name $f$ for two different functions. That will lead to confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ is not uniformly continuous. Suppose it is. Then there exists $\delta >0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<1$ whenever $|x-y|\leq \delta$. Consider $|f(2n\pi)-f(2n\pi +\delta)|$ This must be less than 1 for every $n \in \mathbb N$. However $f(2n\pi)=0$ and $|f(2n\pi+\delta)|=(2n\pi +\delta) \sin (\delta) \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: thanks  u  @Kavi Rama Murty